# ¿Cual puede ser el comando para realizar esta función en la terminal de linux?

Tags: linux, unix, hash, sha256

Estoy necesitando ayuda de alguien con conocimientos en linux, particularmente en el uso de la terminal, hace relativamente poco vi en un conocido un comando, o un conjunto de comandos que generaba un hash de ciertas características, dentro de las mismas se podían apreciar que era un bloque de unas 10 lineas y otra de las particularidades que me llamo la atención es que siempre era un bloque aleatorio, entonces esta persona tenia un alias para esta linea de comandos y cuando lo ejecutaba generaba este bloque de código aleatorio.

Creo que me explique bastante bien,  pero dejare una imagen similar de una pagina que hace algo como lo que busco pero automático y no puedo ver el código detrás. Me interesa que me expliquen como puedo realizar esto para un pequeño proyecto que tengo en mente, algo para pasar el rato y la verdad no tengo los conocimientos para hacerlo solo.

Yo estuve probando con esto:

date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 ; echo

Me funciona pero no puedo hacer que sea de unas 10 lineas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas un bucle `for`, para que haga 10 iteraciones y en esa 10 iteraciones se ejecute el comando y genere 10 diferentes hashes

Comment: esto te podrá servir `for (( c=1; c<=10; c++ )) do date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32; echo; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas posibilidades y combinaciones:

`$ openssl rand -base64 480  | cut -c -32`

`-base64` entrega 64 caracteres por linea

`480` es la cantidad de bytes random antes del base64, 480 + 33% del encoding da masomenos 640 ( 10 lineas de 64 )

`cut` corta las lineas al caracter 32

```
$ openssl rand -base64 480  | cut -c -32
bj8eGrBS0U7zjiIMYoF5pMLvAWqq8pK+
NGdjc1Ft7gQeOSM+HqVBeAZV7a6Oyt5r
69GEO5EhdUamt7sCu8KglXahMv4l5pPK
Gy5UwgDR8CV7Rh0uIlUIr9Ys1fmWEzuA
mdCXLyNUx/D6BqpCNyo9m8Mx8PoJgXEU
eO7fQBb7/lnjLFGh+asgqd845Ic0GKqN
J4qZANPpPWYaN7JdywW509Cwws6erB6n
h8NxwvRSO+ZMC+dsVQqLdcEd+C9BbfFz
0kjWSvdazCPO6ND1R8HAZBygn4euCmJk
s7GVT6MiOt7BPomFs/qmAzJB6gRVsyK0
```

---

`$ head -c 300 /dev/urandom | base64 -w 0 | head -c 320 | sed -e "s/.\{32\}/&\n/g"`

`head -c 300 /dev/urandom` 300 caracteres aleatorios

`base64 -w 0` base64 sin saltos de línea ( +33% = 399 )

`head -c 320` los primeros 320

`sed -e "s/.\{32\}/&\n/g"` insertar salto de línea cada 32 caracteres

```
$ head -c 300 /dev/urandom | base64 -w 0 | head -c 320 | sed -e "s/.\{32\}/&\n/g"
oXshgqVJ9oySW2TcinA1pefRICDzL3jr
STs+N2h5puTxo2AHWCF/6yo04eTZrvly
iv/mPDLYd49TuymyeNmdCLqw7VDnN/t0
o82r1DFmQMVePILlWaJkMNgN+Gpm2nC3
Z4Rs5sm8QZzzzC5w47vceywoaSWws/ia
H5vhTCrt2JJwJN/P2oqgyQjxQVydSnMu
xXmY8HCEVBAT4/D6FNCKs/YCCsRYDyYL
+WT9aqritTre7QMh7SnxFlWTqEdRRjWk
MP1bzAbw+1MlN2D2NKzDc6V3U9aMFs64
rZtEnidiG5BfE5R+oIF/Du4xyzwbpc0I
```

---

`$ openssl rand -hex 160 | fold -w 32`

`-hex 160` 160 hexa bytes = 320 chars

`fold -w 32` acomodar la(s) linea(s) para que tengan 32 caracteres ( alternativa al `sed` )

---

`$ cat /dev/urandom | base64 -w 0 | fold -w 32 | head -n 10`

`cat /dev/urandom` bytes aleatorios

`base64 -w 0` base64 encoding sin marcador de línea

`fold -w 32` limitar la línea a 32 caracteres

`head -n 10` primeras 10 líneas

Comment: Sencillamente perfecto